# Floating point precision with Time - multiply vs divide

Tags: java, android, precision

Will these statements execute with exactly the same results across different platforms?

```
    currentTime = System . nanoTime ( ) * 0.000000001f ; // 01

    currentTime = System . nanoTime ( ) / 1000000000f ; // 02
```

The concern is loss of precision using a small floating point value.

Comment: You might also ask if the same floating point calculation will give you the same result across multiple hardware and OS. Google "floating point determinism".

Comment: Are you trying to code some "atomic" precision watch??

Comment: @RC No atomic precision, just incrementing time at 60 fps ~ 0.017 seconds.  The multiplier precision is okay according to [this floating point bit representation](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) but not sure what happens during the multiplication.

Comment: I would use milliseconds, as nanoTime takes CPU power, and for 60th of seconds, currentTimeMillis is accurate enough.

Comment: If you use milliseconds, you should use the following equation: `frame = (milliseconds * 102 / 100 / 17);` It will be accurate up to 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave it as a long. No loss of precision and perfect Determinism across the board.

Comment: How do you recommend incrementing float values by this time increment?

Comment: Skip the float completely! Just divide by 1e9 for the minutes. Take the modules of 1e9, add 20, and divide by 16666667, and you have your 60th of a second.

Comment: Or even simpler. Just keep the long And divide by 16666666 (long math, ignore remainder). You will lose precision of half second in about 57 hours. The previous method will never lose precision. You will get the same result on all devices and OS.